# Android - Run application on SDK 2.1

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair

Basically, i have purchased HTC Hero (Android sdk 1.5) , but i just got the notification of "System software update" and i agreed to update the **sdk to 2.1-update1** .

I was developing application for android sdk 1.5 successfully, but now i have created a Hello world application for the Android sdk 2.1 and then when i am trying to run it on my updated phone, at that time below screen is showing up:

[image]

***where you can see ?????? in serial number and Taget is shown as "unknown".***

On console window, it is showing up an error: **"Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility."**

**(1st question):** What i need to do to run the application(sdk 2.1) which i am developing ? pls let me know

And ya, when i am trying to connect phone using USB cable, it is showing an alert dialog regarding "Choose a connection type:" showing below options:

1. Charge only
2. HTC Sync
3. Disk drive
4. Internet Sharing

**(2dn question)**: so which mode should i select for the development of application and running it on phone.

Comment: is it listed with you run adb devices ?
usb debuggning enabled ?

Comment: ya USB Debugging Connected message comes if i select "HTC Sync" option is selected, and this options are coming when i attached the USB cable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your udev rules have to be modified. Read [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) to fix them. I don't know why a SDK upgrade should have modified this, but I think this might be your problem.

Comment: Found exactly what i needs -thanx for making my life, i cant give more upvotes otherwise sure give and ya on this page "Setting up a Device for Development" points i have to set, so i set point-3 as i am using Ubuntu Linux.